# Time Machine restore is asking to install MacOS and use Migration tool

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, restore

My MacBook Pro came from service center and I am trying to restore from Time Machine back up. I performed the following step.

- Started mac and pressed command + R
- Selected option to restore from Time Machine
- Selected my hard drive as the source
- Clicked on continue

After this I am suppose to get the option to select Mac hard drive to continue but instead I am getting a pop up. The pop up is asking me to do a fresh install of MacOS and then use Migration tool or select a different source for back up.

Comment: It is possible that the Macbook Pro was repaired and shipped without macOS installed? Command-R (and its variants) starts up from the macOS Recovery system. [This article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) and [this one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) at Apple Support discuss startup key combinations and the Recovery systems respectively.

Comment: macOS is already installed and no changes are done. I am able to login to my existing account. I am trying to restore as I have deleted sensitive information and applications from the mac before submitting it.

Comment: Does the Macbook boot to a user login screen? Can you login to the Macbook with the account you've used in the past?

Comment: Yes. I can login as before.

Comment: The Migration Assistant can be run without reinstalling macOS. You can find it in the Applications > Utilities folder.